# I want to display the json which consists of string and int in list view using retrofit

Tags: android, json, listview, retrofit, retrofit2

[image]

JSON format

I want to display the json in list view ,
here is my code

Call> call = api.getScheduledTasks("atos");

```
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ScheduledTasks>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ScheduledTasks>> call, Response<List<ScheduledTasks>> response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"successsss",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            List<ScheduledTasks> ScheduledTasksList = response.body();
         //   ScheduledTasksList.toString();
            //Creating an String array for the ListView
            String[] scheduledtask = new String[ScheduledTasksList.size()];

            //looping through all the heroes and inserting the names inside the string array
            for (int i = 0; i < ScheduledTasksList.size(); i++) {
                scheduledtask[i] = ScheduledTasksList.get(i).getScheduleId();

            }


            //displaying the string array into listview
            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, scheduledtask));
```

It shows failure ,it doesnt display in list view because of int in json.Kindly provide me the right method,to display both string and int in array.

Comment: Hi Nilesh! It would be helpful to clean up some of the formatting on your post. It seems a little hard to understand. The title seems to be part of the text. Perhaps you could ask the question like this: "How do I display both the string and an int in the array, using (fill in the rest here)?" The JSON image example is too small. The code example needs some cleanup editing too. Should the code above the code block, be in that block? The goal is to make it both readable & reproduceable. If you clean up your question, then perhaps people will be able to help answer it for you. Good luck! :)

Comment: Could you post the class ScheduledTasks?

Answer (score 0):

copy your json response, nothing but image which you upload for this question, and paste in [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) website. then the website(tool) convert your json response to POJO class and you can access easily like calling any setter and getter method.
hope this solve your problem.